# Google Chrome 20: How to workaround poor performance with Flash?

Tags: google-chrome

After the update to "Google Chrome 20.0.1132.47" `google-chrome` started to lag. It gets stuck for couple of seconds and then it resumes. The issue seems to start after I enter any flash site

Running `google-chrome` from terminal results in following errors:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:980:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:623:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:980:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:623:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:980:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:623:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:980:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:623:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:980:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:623:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:980:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:623:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to initialize slave
```

Firefox does not have any problem. Can you suggest a workaround to get Google Chrome to work as it previously did?

Comment: There is a feeling that the new Pepper Flash is causing problems for some users of Chrome 20. The suggestion is to start Chrome with the following switch: `--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash`. You can look at this [thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/linux/UVGRyv50t0E) for more and [this bug page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=134940).

Comment: Could someone comment why this is off-topic? Seems perfectly reasonable to ask here, as it's a "real" problem that someone is having, not opinion-based, and is for Ubuntu not a competing flavor.

Comment: I found this to be on-topic.

Comment: An explanation for why this widely-approved question is off-topic would be especially appropriate now that it has at least one delete vote. We should not delete a question if the reason it was closed is still not clear to the community. "Running third-party applications on Ubuntu" is [explicitly on-topic in the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm having the same problem when using the Chrome version of Flash Player.  Temporary workaround:

1. Install the `adobe-flashplugin` package
2. In Chrome, go to: `chrome://plugins/`
3. Disable the `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so` instance of Flash Player
4. Restart Chrome

Comment: This worked for me too. Chrome was unusable before doing this where it would be 1-2 seconds before it responded to any input (mouse click, keyboard, mouse wheel). It is now acting fine.

Comment: Seems to work fine here, too. Should I expect any adverse side-effects after disabling `libpepflashplayer.so`?

Comment: Possible causes for the problem: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135282 and https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/10662049