# Chromium input fields lag

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Every time I have to insert text into a text field in chromium insertion lags, it stops working for a second and I don't see the text I'm typing (the cursor doesn't move). After a moment the text field works again but after 10 seconds or so it stops again. Very frustrating, same on google chrome.

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the pepper flash has resolved this for me .. (so far)

[Google Chrome 20: How to workaround poor performance with Flash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158009/google-chrome-freezes-for-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Wait I think I found something, are you using an ati card too? if so try updating your ati driver seems to be related to new v8 engine combined with ati driver provided in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, for years! But it finally dawned on me that it wasn't happening in my 'stripped' Chrome user profile which wasn't carrying around a legacy of bookmarks. I stripped out all my obsolete bookmarks from my primary Chrome profile and the problem is gone. Give it a try...