# Error Installing FGLRX driver

Tags: drivers, ati, google-chrome, fglrx

My computer uses a Radeon HD 6950. I installed the "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver" just fine, however, when I tried to install the "post-release updates", I received an error ("Sorry, installation of this driver failed.") The log dump:

```
2012-08-07 20:46:12,739 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-08-07 20:46:17,150 DEBUG: Installing package: fglrx-updates
2012-08-07 20:46:17,459 DEBUG: install progress dpkg-exec 0.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:17,650 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle 0.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:17,718 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle 6.250000
2012-08-07 20:46:17,718 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle 12.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:17,840 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle 18.750000
2012-08-07 20:46:18,387 DEBUG: install progress fglrx 18.750000
2012-08-07 20:46:18,488 DEBUG: install progress fglrx 25.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:22,242 DEBUG: install progress fglrx 31.250000
2012-08-07 20:46:22,899 DEBUG: install progress fglrx 37.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:23,034 DEBUG: install progress bamfdaemon 37.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:23,186 DEBUG: install progress ureadahead 37.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:23,337 DEBUG: install progress initramfs-tools 37.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:31,330 DEBUG: install progress libc-bin 37.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:31,696 DEBUG: install progress dpkg-exec 37.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:32,196 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 37.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:32,297 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 43.750000
2012-08-07 20:46:35,565 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 50.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:35,715 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 56.250000
2012-08-07 20:46:35,993 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 56.250000
2012-08-07 20:46:36,093 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 62.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:36,589 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 68.750000
2012-08-07 20:46:36,679 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 75.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:36,775 DEBUG: install progress ureadahead 75.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:37,096 DEBUG: install progress dpkg-exec 75.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:37,117 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 75.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:37,457 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 81.250000
2012-08-07 20:46:50,763 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-updates 87.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:51,118 DEBUG: install progress bamfdaemon 87.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:51,279 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 87.500000
2012-08-07 20:46:51,346 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 93.750000
2012-08-07 20:46:51,414 DEBUG: install progress fglrx-amdcccle-updates 100.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:51,490 DEBUG: install progress initramfs-tools 100.000000
2012-08-07 20:46:58,956 DEBUG: install progress libc-bin 100.000000
2012-08-07 20:47:00,259 DEBUG: (Reading database ... 176892 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing fglrx-amdcccle ...
Removing fglrx ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf to auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/bin/amdcccle because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdcccle (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amdcccle.desktop because associated file /usr/share/fglrx/amdcccle.desktop (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amdccclesu.desktop because associated file /usr/share/fglrx/amdccclesu.desktop (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/bin/amdupdaterandrconfig because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdupdaterandrconfig (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/bin/amdxdg-su because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdxdg-su (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalcl.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalrt.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalrt.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules with a link.
update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf to auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules with a link.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-27-generic-pae
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-updates.
(Reading database ... 176654 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx-updates (from .../fglrx-updates_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle-updates.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle-updates (from .../fglrx-amdcccle-updates_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up fglrx-updates (2:8.960-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalcl.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalrt.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalrt.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalcl.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalcl.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/lib32/libaticalrt.so because associated file /usr/lib32/fglrx/libaticalrt.so (of link group i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Loading new fglrx-updates-8.960 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.2.0-27-generic-pae
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.2.0-27-generic-pae
Done.

fglrx_updates:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.2.0-27-generic-pae/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle-updates (2:8.960-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-27-generic-pae
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

2012-08-07 20:47:00,427 WARNING: /sys/module/fglrx_updates/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind fglrx_updates driver
2012-08-07 20:47:15,595 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-08-07 20:47:15,595 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
2012-08-07 20:47:15,608 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
2012-08-07 20:47:15,608 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
```

When I restart, I find the original FGLRX is uninstalled, but I can reinstall fine. I have been using just the original (no updates) just fine.

However, I have been experiencing the same Chrome lag as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161228/chromium-input-fields-lag).

Is it related to my driver?

Comment: What is the real question here? The FGLRX part or the Chrome part?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, my real question is the driver install failure. I wasn't sure if I should ask the chrome thing in a separate question, but I thought it was worth mentioning in case they were related. Thank you for fixing the formatting too.

Comment: you're welcome :). Btw you should ask about Chrome in a separate question for best results.